# Instance search limitations

Tags: agda

The instance arguments machinery is described in an old [paper](https://lirias.kuleuven.be/bitstream/123456789/304985/1/icfp001-Devriese.pdf) and [at the Agda wiki](http://wiki.portal.chalmers.se/agda/pmwiki.php?n=ReferenceManual.InstanceArguments). Are there some notable facts that these sources do not mention? What are limitations of instance search?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Removing ambiguity

If we typecheck this:

```
open import Category.Functor
open import Category.Monad
open RawFunctor
open RawMonad
```

and run `C-c C-w _<$>_` (`C-c C-w` is "explain why a particular name in scope"), we get (after some cleaning)

```
_<$>_ is in scope as
  * a record field Category.Functor.RawFunctor._<$>_
  * a record field Category.Monad.RawMonad._._<$>_
```

I.e. `_<$>_` is ambiguous, so it's cumbersome to use monads and functors, that are not monads, in the same module, because you have to manually disambiguate between two `_<$>_`.

This can be cured with instance arguments. Instead of opening `Functor` in the definition of `Monad` (via `Applicatve`):

```
record RawIMonad ... where

  open RawIApplicative rawIApplicative public
```

we can provide an instance and let instance search do the job (the definitions of `Applicative` and `Functor` can be found [here](https://github.com/effectfully/random-stuff/blob/master/liftA.agda)):

```
record Monad {α} (M : Set α -> Set α) : Set (suc α) where
  infixl 1 _>>=_

  field
    return : ∀ {A} -> A -> M A
    _>>=_  : ∀ {A B} -> M A -> (A -> M B) -> M B

  instance
    Monad<:Applicative : Applicative M
    Monad<:Applicative = record { pure = return ; _<*>_ = λ mf mx -> mf >>= λ f -> mx >>= return ∘ f }
open Monad {{...}}
```

Now there is only one `_<$>_` — in the definition of `Functor`, but instance search sees, that a monad is an applicative and an applicative is a functor, so `_<$>_` is defined on monads, because it's defined on functors.

## Instance fields

At the moment you [can't](https://code.google.com/p/agda/issues/detail?id=1273) declare fields of records as instances:

```
record R : Set where
  field
    instance n : ℕ
```

The workaround is

```
record R : Set where
  field
    n : ℕ

   instance
     R->ℕ : ℕ
     R->ℕ = n
```

## Weakness

Instance search doesn't cooperate with metavariables resolution.

```
instance
  fz : Fin 1
  fz = zero

z : ∀ {n} {{_ : Fin n}} -> ℕ
z = 0

yellow : z ≡ 0
yellow = refl

ok : z {1} ≡ 0
ok = refl
```

In `yellow` instance search doesn't find the `fz` instance. I [was told](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.agda/7759), that this is the intended behaviour, but it looks too restrictive to me and I don't see any benefits.

One workaround is to use instance arguments in place of implicit arguments:

```
instance
  one : ℕ
  one = 1

  fz : Fin 1
  fz = zero

  z : ∀ {{n}} {{_ : Fin n}} -> ℕ
  z = 0

  now-ok : z ≡ 0
  now-ok = refl
```

## [Instances are always imported](https://code.google.com/p/agda/issues/detail?id=1265)

```
module M where
  instance
    z : ℕ
    z = 0

z' : {{n : ℕ}} -> ℕ
z' {{n}} = n

ok : z' ≡ 0
ok = refl
```

The `M` module is not opened, but the instance is in scope. If you want to hide instances, use records:

```
record R : Set where
  instance
    z : ℕ
    z = 0

z' : {{n : ℕ}} -> ℕ
z' {{n}} = n

error : z' ≡ 0
error = refl

open R _

ok : z' ≡ 0
ok = refl
```

## [A nasty bug](https://code.google.com/p/agda/issues/detail?id=1604&can=1&q=effectfully)

We can rewrite `ok` as

```
ok : let open R _ in z' ≡ 0
ok = refl
```

But if define `ok'` below

```
ok' : z' ≡ 0
ok' = refl
```

The instance from `R` is not in scope, but Agda picks it anyway. The same holds for the value level. I.e. if you import a module or open a record, instances from it will be availaible for all definitions below, regardless of where you opened it.

## Personal experience

I was fighting with instance arguments for two weeks or so, trying to [implement](https://github.com/effectfully/random-stuff/tree/master/Categories) some basic category theory in Agda, but instance search is unpredictable because of its weakness — adding a parameter to a record ruins everything. It's also hard to figure why everything is yellow — is it because you are doing something silly or because Agda refuses to resolve a trivial metavariable? When you have a type signature on six lines and several nested records, it's a matter of luck, whether you'll find a way to overcome instance search limitations or not.