# How does adding an instance parameter help instance search?

Tags: agda

By accident, I managed to get instance search to succeed but I don't understand why.

In the code below, why does `test2` succeed but `test1` fail (with unsolved metas & constraints)? How does the addition of the `⦃ isRelation ⦄` parameter to `IsSymmetric2` help? I figure it must somehow have to do with some metas getting solved, therefore allowing instance search to succeed, but beyond that I'm quite foggy.

Can someone shed light on the mechanics at work here?

There is an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31544735/1312174) that touches on my question (the "Weakness" section) but there is no explanation there of the mechanics of how the workaround works. I'm guessing that an answer to the present question will help me better understand that workaround.

```
{-# OPTIONS --show-implicit #-}

record IsSymmetric1 {A : Set} (F : A → A → A) (Q : A → A → Set) : Set where
  field
    symmetry1 : ∀ {x y} → Q (F x y) (F y x)

open IsSymmetric1 ⦃ … ⦄

record IsRelation {A : Set} (Q : A → A → Set) : Set where
  no-eta-equality

record IsSymmetric2 {A : Set} (F : A → A → A) (Q : A → A → Set) ⦃ isRelation : IsRelation Q ⦄ : Set where
  field
    symmetry2 : ∀ {x y} → Q (F x y) (F y x)

open IsSymmetric2 ⦃ … ⦄

postulate
  B : Set
  G : B → B → B
  R : B → B → Set
  instance I-IsSymmetric1 : IsSymmetric1 {B} G R
  instance I-IsRelation : IsRelation R
  instance I-IsSymmetric2 : IsSymmetric2 {B} G R

test1 : ∀ {x y} → R (G x y) (G y x)
test1 = symmetry1 -- yellow unless {F = G} or {Q = R} is specified


test2 : ∀ {x y} → R (G x y) (G y x)
test2 = symmetry2
```

The errors and unsolved metas reported by the typechecker for `test1` are:

```
_A_39 : Set  [ at ….agda:29,9-18 ]
_F_40 : _A_39 {.x} {.y} → _A_39 {.x} {.y} → _A_39 {.x} {.y}  [ at ….agda:29,9-18 ]
_Q_41 : _A_39 {.x} {.y} → _A_39 {.x} {.y} → Set  [ at ….agda:29,9-18 ]
_r_42 : IsSymmetric1 {_A_39 {.x} {.y}} (_F_40 {.x} {.y}) (_Q_41 {.x} {.y})  [ at ….agda:29,9-18 ]
_x_43 : _A_39 {.x} {.y}  [ at ….agda:29,9-18 ]
_y_44 : _A_39 {.x} {.y}  [ at ….agda:29,9-18 ]
_45 : R (G .x .y) (G .y .x)  [ at ….agda:29,9-18 ]
_46 : R (G .x .y) (G .y .x)  [ at ….agda:29,9-18 ]

———— Errors ————————————————————————————————————————————————
Failed to solve the following constraints:
  Resolve instance argument
    _42 :
      {.x .y : B} →
      IsSymmetric1 {_A_39 {.x} {.y}} (_F_40 {.x} {.y}) (_Q_41 {.x} {.y})
  Candidates I-IsSymmetric1 : IsSymmetric1 {B} G R
  [55] _Q_41 {.x} {.y}
       (_F_40 {.x} {.y} (_x_43 {.x} {.y}) (_y_44 {.x} {.y}))
       (_F_40 {.x} {.y} (_y_44 {.x} {.y}) (_x_43 {.x} {.y}))
       =< R (G .x .y) (G .y .x)
         : Set
  _45 :=
    λ {.x} {.y} →
      IsSymmetric1.symmetry1 (_r_42 {.x} {.y}) {_x_43 {.x} {.y}}
      {_y_44 {.x} {.y}}
    [blocked on problem 55]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problematic metavariable is `_Q_41`, i.e. the Q argument to `symmetry1`. It should be clear from the constraint `[55]` that there isn't a unique solution for `_Q_41` (for instance both `R` and `flip R` are potential solutions).

When you add the `IsRelation Q` constraint this turns into `IsRelation {_A39 {.x} {.y}} (_Q_41 {.x} {.y})` in `test2`. Usually instance search doesn't touch a constraint like that since the principal argument is a metavariable, but in this case the metavariable is *constrained* (see [1]), so instance search proceeds. The only available instance is `IsRelation R`, and choosing this solution forces  `_Q_41` to be `R`.

If you were to add an instance `IsRelation (flip R)` the example would no longer go through, since instance search couldn't choose between the two `IsRelation` instances without knowing more about `_Q_41`.

[1] http://agda.readthedocs.io/en/latest/language/instance-arguments.html#instance-resolution